# Why couldn't Spring Security match the login request while using ajax request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am building a project with Spring Security and Spring Boot, but when I login with ajax request, Spring Security's request matcher can not match the login request `/auth/login`, 
I want to know how I could configure it correctly.

This is my WebSecurity Configuration:

```java
package com.keanu.blog.web.config;

import com.keanu.blog.web.security.GlobalAuthenticationFilter;
import com.keanu.blog.web.security.LoginAuthenticationProvider;
import com.keanu.blog.web.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import com.keanu.blog.web.security.TokenAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;

/**
 *
 * @author leiyongqi
 * @date 2019/07/27
 */

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/registry").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and()
                .addFilter(globalAuthenticationFilter());

    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
    }

    @Bean("loginAuthenticationProvider")
    public AuthenticationProvider loginAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new LoginAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean("tokenAuthenticationProvider")
    public AuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public GlobalAuthenticationFilter globalAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        GlobalAuthenticationFilter globalAuthenticationFilter = new GlobalAuthenticationFilter();
        globalAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return globalAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(loginAuthenticationProvider())
                .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**","/druid/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

And this is My GlobalAuthenticationFilter.class, every request can be intercepted by this filter.

```java
package com.keanu.blog.web.security;

import com.keanu.blog.common.constant.AuthConstant;
import com.keanu.blog.common.utils.AesUtil;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Custom Authentication Filter (Both Username and Token)
 * @author leiyongqi
 * @date 2019/08/01
 */
@Slf4j
public class GlobalAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private String keyParameter = "key";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        try {
            // Authenticate with username
            if (isLoginRequest(request, response)) {
                Authentication authentication = processLogin(request, response);
                successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authentication);
                return;
            }

            // If the request isn't login request, authenticate with jwt token
            // TODO Authenticate with jwt token
            String token = obtainJwtToken(request);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, e);
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

    private String obtainJwtToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader(AuthConstant.JWT_TOKEN_HEADER);
    }

    private boolean isLoginRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return requiresAuthentication(request, response) && "POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod());
    }

    private String obtainSecretKey(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameter(keyParameter);
    }

    private Authentication processLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        String encryptPassword = obtainPassword(request);
        String key = obtainSecretKey(request);

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("处理登录请求：username[{}], password[{}], secretKey[{}]", username, encryptPassword, key);
        }

        // 解密密码以及用 BCryptPasswordEncoder 加密
        String password = null;
        try {
            password = AesUtil.encryptPassword(AesUtil.decryptAes(encryptPassword, key));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("解密密码失败：password[{}], key[{}], error[{}]", encryptPassword, key, e.getMessage());
        }

        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        Authentication responseAuth = getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authentication);
        if (responseAuth == null || !responseAuth.isAuthenticated()) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("Unable to authenticate User for provided credentials");
        }

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("登录用户 [{}] 验证成功", username);
        }

        return responseAuth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        response.getWriter().write("");
    }
}
```

but if I use ajax to send login request using url `/auth/login`, Spring Security can not match the login request so I can't handle the login request.

this is my Login Page's ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: loginUrl,    // loginUrl => '/auth/login'
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({'username': username, 'password': encryptPwd, 'secretKey': key}),
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                window.localStorage.setItem("JWT-TOKEN", data);
                window.location.href = "/";
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("登录失败：" + e.message);
            }
        })
```

Through checking the source code, the request can't go into the 'handle login' block because `requiresAuthentication(request)` can't match the login pattern with '/auth/login', but I don' t know why.

I expected the login request with ajax to be intercepted by Spring Security so the request could go into 'handle login' block I showed above.

Comment: What happens when you send a request via ajax? What response do you get?

Comment: @NatFar There is no exception, the response is authentication failed, but I the request is login request, so I expected the request go into the `handle login ` block to handle login request.

Comment: Maybe I describe it not well, all requests can not go into the `handle login`  if block even if it is login request, so I can't login to see the index page.

Comment: Does it work successfully when you use SOAPUI or Postman?

Comment: try adding http.csrf().disable(); Does the request go through?

Comment: @leiyongqi Show your full Spring Security configuration, not only one line. Show your request with headers, for example a screenshot of your dev tool in your browser (F12).

Comment: @dur Oh, I'm sorry. I am supposed to put all the codes on it. I have tried to add http.csrf().disable(), it' s not the problem. I have tried ALL ways I know, but still don't solve it. I'll show my whole project later, I'm on work now, Sorry. Thanks for your reply.Sorry!!!!!!!!!!!!!!